# ¿Cómo consultar datos de una tabla desde php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

no logro hacer la siguiente consulta (soy principiante) ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <title>Universalistas</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>

<body>
<p>hola</p>

<?php

    $host = "xxxxxx";
    $user = "xxxxxx";
    $pass = "xxxxxx";
    $name = "xxxxxx";


    $con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $name);

    if(mysqli_connect_errno()) echo "" . mysqli_connect_error();
    if(mysqli_ping($con)) echo "ok!";
    else echo "" . mysqli_error($con);

    /*$user = "test";
    $password = "test";
    $mail = "tes@test.test";
    $name = "test";
    $lastname = "test";
    $origin = "test";
    $area = "test";*/

 $conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $name);

    $reg = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from users;");
    if($reg)
    {
        echo "<script>alert('Usuario registrado correctamente.'); 
        window.location.href = 'index.php';</script>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Ño"/*"<script>alert('¡Ha ocurrido un error y no se     registraron los datos!'); 
        window.location.href = 'index.php';</script>"*/;
    }

?>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: podias dar mas detalles de tu problema?

Comment: Añade tu error al momento de ejecutar tú consulta por favor.

Comment: Pues probé el código haciendo uso de xampp y funcionó pero ahora lo estoy tratando de pasar a godaddy y simplemente me lleva a la condición else, cómo puedo abrir una consola? no sé más detalles simplemente no hace la consulta, ya tengo la base de datos creada en godaddy

Comment: Tú consulta es un Select no un insert

Comment: Sí, lo sé. Estoy intentando varias cosas para ver qué pasa pero no encuentro el error

Comment: Estás haciendo una consulta que devuelve un "arreglo" con todos los usuarios y por lo tanto deberías recorrerla con un foreach o un while, saludos.

Comment: No has seleccionado una base de datos. Por lo que no sabe donde buscar la tabla si no has seleccionado la base de datos

Answer (score 1):

Lo más seguro es que la configuración de tu servidor esté suprimiendo errores y no puedes programar con claridad. Agrega las siguientes dos líneas al inicio de tu script para que puedas ver que error envía:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Otra opción es meter TODO dentro de un bloque `try catch`

```
try {
   $conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $name);
   $reg = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from users;");
   if($reg) {
     echo "Si";
   } else {
     echo "Ño";
   }
} catch (Exception $exc) {
   echo '<pre>';
   var_export($exc);
   echo '<br>';
}
```

Hay probabilidad de que no tengas siquiera una conexión abierta a la base de datos pero como PHP está suprimiendo los errores tu ni en cuenta...